# How to Add an Arbitrary Attribute to an HTML Tag Using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to dynamically designate some `<button>`s as having a value like `correct=true` or `correct=false`. I see how to use 
Ideally this attribute would be invisible to the a user clicking 'view source.'
I can live with the answer being visible via a JavaScript debugger.

Right now I am storing it in a separate data structure and looking it up via the id which is dynamically constructed by AngularJS:

```
<div style="padding-top: 5px" class="col-md-offset-3" ng-repeat="answer in answers">
   <button id="answerChoice_{{$index}}" 
           style="font-size: 18px;" 
           class="btn btn-default" 
           ng-click="selectButton($event)" >

           {{answer}}

   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered HTML 5 `data-` attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng comes with jquery light version so you can script something like

```
$('button').attr("correct",true);
```

Comment: When I add required attr, the form is not being validated as required. Only when I write it by hand the required validation is fired.