# Adding/Removing checked attribute to checkbox dynamiclly in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can i simply add and remove checked attribute to check-box using angularjs.
I've find solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501942/how-to-add-an-arbitrary-attribute-to-an-html-tag-using-angularjs) question,but it requires Jquery

Is any other way to do this without using Jquery?

Here is what i am tried

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test"  class="switch__input" checked="{{checkVal}}">
<input type="button" ng-click="test()" value="test">
```

**JS**

```
 module.controller('settingsCtrl',function($scope){
  //for adding
  $scope.checkVal="checked";
  //for removing checkbox
  $scope.test=function(){
   $scope.CheckVal="";
  }
}
```

But the removing wont work

Comment: Looks like you have a typo. The second CheckVal is capitalized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) recommended way of check and un check checkbox

**HTML** :
`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkVal" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">`

Also works

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkVal">
```

**JS** :

```
module.controller('settingsCtrl',function($scope){
  //for adding
  $scope.checkVal=true;
  //for removing checkbox
  $scope.test=function(){
   $scope.checkVal=false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need special directive for this, [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) would work well:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []).controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkVal = true;

  $scope.test = function() {
    $scope.checkVal = !$scope.checkVal; // or false
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainController">
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" class="switch__input" ng-checked="checkVal">
    <input type="button" ng-click="test()" value="test">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check working example : [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/kBLtLMUlbAsOOLOqMUtK?p=preview)

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" class="switch__input" ng-checked="checkVal">
<input type="button" ng-click="test()" value="test">
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.checkVal = true;
    //for adding/removing checkbox
    $scope.test = function() {
           $scope.checkVal = !$scope.checkVal;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can across a directive to add dynamic attribute may be this can help you

```
  myApp.directive('dynAttr', function() {
return {
    scope: { list: '=dynAttr' },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        for(attr in scope.list){
            elem.attr(scope.list[attr].attr, scope.list[attr].value);   
        }
        //console.log(scope.list);           
    }
};
});
```

In the controller

```
$scope.attArray = [
{ attr: 'myattribute', value: '' }
];
```

Use it as

```
<input dyn-attrs="attArray"></input>
```

Comment: There is no way without using directive?